# How to check if a field type Any? is nil o NSNull

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm actually trying to parse a Json object with Swift3 on Xcode8.1.
This is my code:

```
if let objData = objJson["DATA"] as! NSDictionary? {
    var msg: String = ""
    if let tmp = objData.object(forKey: "Message") { 
        msg = tmp as! String
    } else {
        print("NIIILLLLL")
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error message: `Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x4587b68) to 'NSString' (0x366d5f4)` at this line `msg = tmp as! String`.

I'm not understanding why I'm getting this error because the type of tmp is `Any` and it should display the print instead of convert `tmp as! String`

Thank you for the help,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add casting in `let`.

```
if let tmp = objData.object(forKey: "Message") as? String { 
    msg = tmp
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With Swift 3, for example:

```
fileprivate var rawNull: NSNull = NSNull()
public var object: Any {
   get {
      return self.rawNull
   }
}
```

You can check field object as:

```
if self.object is NSNull {
  // nil
}
```

Comment: obj is NSNull is the cure

Comment: Unfortunately my app crashes with `Thread 1: "-[NSNull _fastCStringContents:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` hen using `is NSNull`

Answer (score 0):

So to answer your question in why you are getting that error, in your code "tmp" is not nil its something of type NSNull (if you want to know more about NSNull check the docs) but its basically "A singleton object used to represent null values in collection objects that don’t allow nil values." 
The rest is just you are force casting which I recommend avoiding this is a safer way to do what you are doing.

```
guard let objData = objJson["DATA"] as? [String: Any], let msg = objData["Message"] else { return }
// now you can use msg only if exists and also important keeping its unmutable state
```